# Shopify Create Custom field for Showing more information

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I need to show users more information about the products, so I need more fields to save the products.
There are lots of apps that do it, But is there any dev's way of doing it?

P.S. I have found lots of posts about the users adding additional info while add to cart and checkout. But it's admin adding additional info for the users that i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

admin/metafields/product

Here we can create Metafeilds.